# Maximal Solution to $y''+9y=6\cos 3t$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The questions asks for general and particular solutions for the above DE and maximal solution. I solved general and particular one.

But this question statement 
I am unable to solve:**Compute the maximal solution of the Cauchy’s problem for the initial conditions $y(0) = 0, y'(0) = 1$.**
Determine also the interval of the maximal solution.

$$y''+9y=6\cos 3t$$

**I have researched a lot regarding this but everywhere I found first order maximal solution not for 2nd order.**

And whatever resources are found it is so much english theory like galois theory, and i really dont like that part. Can anyone send its simple meaning in terms of mathematic equations and solve this 2nd order and any 1st order case also

Comment: This is a linear equation. You can certainly fin the general solution of the homogenoeus equation ,  and find a particular solution. of your initial equation. Then just plug into your two initial conditions...

Comment: I'm confused.  There's only one solution to the IVP, so how can we talk of a "maximal" solution?  Also, "Cauchy's problem" usually refers to a PDE.  This is an ODE.  I don't think the problem is well-posed.

Comment: will it yield maximal solution ?

Comment: @B.Goddard, yeah on internet it is everywhere... for 1st order

Comment: But first order PARTIAL DE.  You have an ODE.  I don't think anyone understands what a "maximal solution" is in this context.

Comment: so i guess @B.Goddard this is invalid  you mean ?

Comment: It may be terminology I've never heard of, but I believe that asking for a "maximal solution" to a problem that has only one solution makes no sense.  I point out again that these "first order" things you're finding online are about PARTIAL DE's.  You have an ODE.  The problem might make sense if there were some sort of parameter in the problem, for instance, if $y'(0) = \lambda$ or the $9$ was changed to a $k$.

Comment: I think "maximal" just means "on the largest possible domain" in this context.

Comment: @Ian  But that doesn't explain the reference to Cauchy's problem.  I think I know what's going on, but we really need the OP to carefully check the problem statement.

Comment: @B.Goddard Cauchy problem is just a formal term for initial value problem.